# Error in my server logs

Tags: bind

I get this whenever I check my bind status. Any ideas??

```
 Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: _default/uzbekistan.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: file not found
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: zone venezuela.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loading from master file /etc/named/Zone/venezuela.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu failed: file not found
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: zone venezuela.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: _default/venezuela.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: file not found
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: zone vietnam.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loading from master file /etc/named/Zone/vietnam.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu failed: file not found
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: zone vietnam.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: _default/vietnam.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: file not found
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: zone zambia.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loading from master file /etc/named/Zone/zambia.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu failed: file not found
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: zone zambia.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Mar 17 01:03:19 node070 bash[15777]: _default/zambia.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: file not found
```

EDIT: **Now I get this**

```
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-03-17 01:47:27 EDT; 2s ago
  Process: 15735 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/rndc stop > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11677 ExecReload=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/rndc reload > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13442 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16047 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13445 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 bash[16047]: zone 
united_states.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loaded serial 3456789
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 bash[16047]: zone uruguay.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loaded serial 3456789
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 bash[16047]: zone uzbekistan.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loaded serial 3456789
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 bash[16047]: zone venezuela.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loaded serial 3456789
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 bash[16047]: zone vietnam.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loaded serial 3456789
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 bash[16047]: zone zambia.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu/IN: loaded serial 3456789
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Mar 17 01:47:27 node070 systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

Comment: What's process 15777? How do you check your bind status, in other words, where do you find these messages?

Comment: So I actually edited a file or two and now im getting these. 
I redited the original post to include new info

Comment: Know that bind will fail to start when there’s any critical errors in your configuration or zone data. Usually those errors aren’t captured in systemd and the journal but in the bind log files. Otherwise manually run `named-checkzone <domain.com> <zone file with location>` for all your domains and zone files.

Comment: What is not clear in "file /etc/named/Zone/zambia.jhasb006.cts4348.fiu.edu failed: file not found" ? You reference a filename that does not exist on disk, so things don't work. You need to make this file exists or change the name to point it where it is really.

Answer (score 0):

Your `named` config, usually `/etc/named.conf` (see `systemctl show -p Environment named.service`) is buggy, `named-checkconf` failed with return code *1*.

See https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/bind/blob/rawhide/f/named.service

Run `named-checkconf <conf>` and solve the problem.